# AWS Site to Site OPENVPN

Tags: networking, vpn, routing, openvpn, amazon-web-services

I have a openvpn appliance access server in AWS and a openvpn on-premise client(Ubuntu) within a NAT (a bunch of Virutalbox servers for testing). I have connected successfully to AWS OpenVPN server and can ping the openvpn server from openvpn client fine. Correct me if I am wrong but if I wanted AWS servers to communicate with the servers in the NAT like the openvpn client , then I would need to setup a site to site?

Is the only way to do this is with Virtual Private Gateway on the AWS side? I would rather not pay extra for this. I would rather add static routes on both sides in order for each side to communicate. Any help?

Diagram of what I am trying to achieve:
VBOX NAT--> DD-WRT(OpenVPN Client) --> Internet -->AWS VPC --> AWS OpenVPN Appliance.

VBOX NAT <-- DD-WRT(OpenVPN Client) <--Internet <-- AWS VPC <-- AWS OpenVPN Appliance.

Answer (score 2):

A Virtual Private Gateway is IPSec -- not SSL, which is what OpenVPN uses for tunnels -- so the good news is you don't need it, and the bad news is you can't use it for this, anyway.

For your proposed setup, the static route(s) for the external subnet(s) go(es) in the VPC routing tables, with the target configured by specifying the instance ID of your gateway machine -- not its IP address, as you would in an Ethernet LAN router.  You don't change the route tables of the other EC2 instances at all, for a setup like this.

Then, you [disable the IP address source/destination check](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/VPC_NAT_Instance.html#EIP_Disable_SrcDestCheck)  on the gateway instance -- this allows it to forward traffic to your other instances with source addresses other than its own (the external private subnets).  Note that the section of docs I've linked to is actually the section for configuring NAT instances, so disregard the remainder of the information there -- but the feature you need to disable is the same for an instance providing tunnels to subnets external to your VPC.

Comment: I will need to use the VPN Client Gateway on AWS to set these static tables right?

Comment: You'll do this in the [VPC Route Tables](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/VPC_Route_Tables.html).

Comment: Ok thanks . How about the client side which is Ubuntu and has openvpn client. Where do I set static routes on that side seeing I have a NAT.

Comment: Openvpn can push routes to the client, so you should be able to configure those routes on the openvpn appliance and for the client to pick up when it connects.

Comment: Can't get this to work.  Here what I have done. I went into AWS VPC>Route Tables and added  10.0.2.0/24(Dest) to ID of my OPENVPN instance. The IP of the VBOX Instance is 10.0.2.5/24(NAT). Then I disabled the source/dest check. I restarted the OpenVPN Server and Restarted the OpenVPN Client in the VBOX NAT. I ping the IP of the OPENVPN Server from OPENVPN Client in the VBOX NAT and it worked.  However I could not ping from OPENVPN Server to the VBOX Instance(OpenVPN Client) 10.0.2.5 . What am I missing? Do I need to do something within the OPENVPN Server Admin page?

Comment: Is [`net.ipv4.forward = 1`](http://askubuntu.com/a/311054/94176) enabled on the openvpn machine?

Comment: Also, the IP range of the VPN clients can't overlap with the VPC's CIDR supernet.  What's the VPC's address block?

Comment: I apologize for the delay. VPC address block: 172.31.16.0/20 . I was able to get the site to site tunnel . OpenVPN Server can ping OpenVPN Client and vice versa. However the sever can only ping the client (10.0.2.3) but none of the computers on the client side( subnet 10.0.2.0/24).

Comment: It sounds like you need to break out some wireshark and watch for the server's ping requests and the expected responses on the server, the client, and the other machine on the client network and see how far the traffic gets... remembering that "A can't ping B" means many things: A has no route to B, A has wrong route to B, A has the correct intended route to B but an intermediate machine doesn't handle the traffic properly... and all those same conditions in the reverse direction. A can't ping B *might* mean that A *can* succesfully send a ping to B but that A can't see B's response.

Comment: @BenjaminJones what does `ip route get client-side-address` (put a 10.0.2.0/24 address here) on the server give? It could be either a routing or a firewall issue.

Answer (score -1):

Here's a detailed step-by-step guide of what Michael suggested in his answer - https://opsdocks.com/posts/configure-site-to-site-openvpn/. No private gateways, just EC2s with OpenVPN community edition and some VPC tweaking.